# No visible interface declares the method xx

Tags: ios, objective-c

Getting this error for the method `setCircle` as you see in the photograph. It makes no sense at all: the method above, `setIsToday:`, is recognised just fine and is declared only once, directly above the `setCircle` method. as you can see, the method exists in the code only once, with two calls of this form:

```
[cell setIsToday];
```

which succeeded in both cases. If I do:

```
[cell setCircle];
```

instead I get the error.

[image]

Tried an Xcode restart, clean build, etc. No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you calling it from? If you are calling it from another object, `setCircle` must be declared in your .h header. Perhaps you forgot?

Comment: Both methods are in a UICollectioViewCell subclass, setIsToday is not declared in .h

Comment: Then why are you not calling [self setCircle]?

Comment: PDTSimpleCalendarViewCell *cell = (PDTSimpleCalendarViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setCircle];
    [cell setIsToday:TRUE];

Comment: I don't see how you can call this method in another object without having the method publicly declared in the class's interface. Why don't you try that?

Comment: Ok, but the point is that setCircle and setIsToday are identical and declared in the same way, and the first is not recognised and the second is

Comment: I agree that this seems strange, but if I were you I'd try declaring them both in your public interface.

Comment: Is the property `isToday` declared in your .h file ? If so, then the setter method is implicitly defined for you

Comment: Yes Paulw11 the isToday property is declared in the .h. I didn't know that you could do this, thanks, solved the problem!! If you give an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call `[cell setIsToday];` as the method is `-(void)setIsToday:(BOOL)isToday` (note the parameter).

You need to call either `[cell setIsToday:YES]` or `[cell setIsToday:NO]`